# Flask CSS loading issues with redirect

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I want people to be redirected to the route /profil when they join the app if they are not registered. The problem is that either CSS and Javascript won't load on the page (whereas they do when I delete the following code) :

```
@app.before_request
def before_request_func():
    global ip_addr
    ip_addr=request.environ.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', request.remote_addr)
    if not(ip_addr in [i[2] for i in auth.getUsers()]) and request.path!='/profil':
        return redirect(url_for('profil'))
```

More, the server shell prints :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2022 20:28:23] "GET /profil HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2022 20:28:23] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2022 20:28:23] "GET /static/javascript/script.js HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2022 20:28:23] "GET /profil HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2022 20:28:23] "GET /profil HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Here are my other source codes :

> base.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" >
    <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='css/style.css') }}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../static/images/logo.png" />
  <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <canvas id="c" class="bg"></canvas>
    <div id="profil">{{username}}</div>
      <div id="content">
            {% block content %} {% endblock %}
      <a href="{{url_for('index')}}">
        </div>
      <div class="prospectus">
        <div class="trademark">
          <p class="trademark_style">DECRYPTO </p>
          <p>©2022 Décrypto</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
      <script src="../static/javascript/script.js"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> profil.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Authentification{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
{%endblock%}
```

If someone has any idea on how to fix it... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After some more reflexions, I figured out the problem which is quite simple yo solve : when the client was requesting CSS, it was redirected to the profile route (making an infinite loop). To fix it, we can simply modify the condition as following :

```
@app.before_request
def before_request_func():
    global ip_addr
    ip_addr=request.environ.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', request.remote_addr)
    if not(ip_addr in [i[2] for i in auth.getUsers()]) and not(request.path in ['/profil','/static/CSS/style.css','/static/javascript/script.js']):
        return redirect(url_for('profil'))
```